# Импорт классов в Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

Есть вот такая структура файлов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаемый файл test.py в начале, которого

```
from .observer import Observer
```

При выполнении выдает

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 1, in
 <module>
     from .observer import Observer ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.observer'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Помогите разобраться с импортом классов из других файлов.

Comment: Если вы запускаете `Observer1/test.py`, то никакого модуля `Observer1` у вас не существует и вы не можете из него импортировать подмодули (и файл `__init__.py` при этом абсолютно бесполезен). Или импортируйте соседние файлы как обычные модули `from observer import Observer`, или не запускайте `test.py` напрямую

Comment: @andreymal, т.е. мне нужно вынести test.py за observer1? Тогда __init__.py будет полезен и импорт делать from Observer1 import observer?

Comment: Как вариант. Или (вчера не вспомнил) запускайте файл не как файл, а как подмодуль `python -m Observer1.test`